# Encryption with Azure Key Vault CryptographyClient - where is encrypt/decrypt happenning? my backend or Azure server side

Tags: azure-keyvault, encryption-asymmetric, azure-sdk-.net

I'm currently using Azure Key vault .net SDK to encrypt/decrypt some data. Azure SDK for .net has a build-in Class called "**CryptographyClient**" and it has built-in method for doing that:
[CryptographyClient.decrypt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.security.keyvault.keys.cryptography.cryptographyclient.decrypt?view=azure-java-stable) and [CryptographyClient.encrypt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.security.keyvault.keys.cryptography.cryptographyclient.encrypt?view=azure-java-stable#com-azure-security-keyvault-keys-cryptography-cryptographyclient-encrypt(com-azure-security-keyvault-keys-cryptography-models-encryptparameters-com-azure-core-util-context))

The key I'm using is a RSA key and algorithm I use is RsaOaep, so I assume it is **asymmetric encryption**. I followed this [article](https://endjin.com/blog/2020/07/using-azure-key-vault-for-encryption-in-csharp-a-simple-tutorial) to write my c# code. Basically, I get the public part of the asymmetric key from the key vault first, then use it to create a CryptographyClient.

Usually, for asymmetric encryption, we gonna use the public key to encrypt while the private key is for decryption only. So basically, the private key will **never leave** the Azure Key Vault (always at the Azure server, is it true?).

Now my question is:

when I call **CryptographyClient.encrypt**, is it only running on the client-side (my local server)? or will it send my plaintext to Azure server and send back the encrypted text?

when I call **CryptographyClient.decrypt**, since the private key should never leave Azure and you can only decrypt with private key, is it only running on the Azure server-side? Mean that my local server will need to send the encrypted text to Azure and wait for decryption?

I got a feeling that both of those methods are only happening on the client-side and this is what I want. But then it doesn't make sense for decryption.

Thanks for the clarification as I can't find any MS documentation for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Operations that use the public key - if they can download the public get i.e., caller has the "get" permission - will happen on the client. They public key is download and operation performed. If the caller doesn't have the "get" permission on that key, the operation will be performed on the service.

These operations include:

- encrypt
- verify
- wrap

Operations that require the private key will always be performed on the service, unless you created a CryptographyClient from your own JSON web key (JWK) that has both the public and private keys.

These operations include:

*decrypt
*sign
*unwrap

Answer (score 0):

All of the encryption/decryption occurs on the server side since that’s where the private key lives.

The CryptographyClient API is based on REST :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/keys/encrypt

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/keys/decrypt/decrypt

You can run a Fiddler trace while executing your code to see the server communication.

Comment: Thanks, Matt. The "Server Side" you referred here means Azure server right?  I understand the decryption part as it will need the private key. But for encryption, why it need to happen on Azure Server? Encryption only needs the public key.

Comment: Encryption only requires the public key. If the user has the "get" permission for a key, `CryptographyClient` tries to download it. See my answer for details (note: I wrote it. :))

Comment: This really got me thinking about yesterday as I've only used encrypt/decrypt with symmetric keys..  Thanks for the info.